# In mysql how can I sum 2 columns in different tables and group by a common column

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have two tables:

Doctor

```
Headings wardName, x, y, docYears
```

Nurse

```
Headings wardName, a, b, nurseYear
```

There are several rows with the same wardName in each table. I want to sum all of the docYears+nurseYears for each wardName. At the moment I have this:

```
SELECT Doctor.wardName, SUM(docYears+nurseYears) AS Total 
FROM Doctor 
JOIN Nurse WHERE Doctor.wardName=Nurse.wardName 
GROUP BY Doctor.wardName, Nurse.wardName;
```

And this effectively giving the sum(docYears)*number of rows nurses + sum(nurseYears)*number of rows of doctors for each ward. I don't want to have it multiplying by the number of rows in the other table as this gives the incorrect answer. Could anyone help me rectify this please?

Comment: First, I recommend using some formatting on your code in your question. Just highlight the lines containing your SQL statements and click on the code icon in the formatting toolbar of the editor. This will add an indentation of 4 spaces, signaling the Markdown preprocessor that it is a block of code. People who'd like to answer can more easily read your question in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your WHERE Line and instead do this:

```
FROM Doctor JOIN Nurse ON Nurse.wardName = Doctor.wardName
```

Comment: This still leads to the same problem